# How to input half-width characters in Mozc (fcitx)?

Tags: input-method, fcitx

I don't seem to find any way to configure `mozc-fcitx`. By default, full-width characters are entered, which include even spaces. Is there a way to use `mozc-fcitx` to input half-width characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/questions/169835/where-are-mozc-settings, the command `/usr/lib/mozc/mozc_tool --mode=config_dialog` launches mozc settings.